# Problema a la hora de modificar una textView que se encuentra en otro formulario

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un problema a la hora de cambiar el texto de una `texView` que se encuentra en el primer *layout* pulsando un botón que está en el segundo *layout*.

La cosa es que si me deja cambiarlo al revés (del primer *layout* al segundo).

Adjunto las dos `MainActivity` que utilizo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button siguiente;
    static EditText nombre;
    static TextView decision;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        siguiente =(Button)findViewById(R.id.VerificarBtn);
        nombre =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.NombreEt);
        decision =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultadoTv);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(siguiente);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView saludo;
    Button Aceptar;
    Button Rechazar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Aceptar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.AceptarBtn);
        Rechazar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.RechazarBtn);
        saludo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SaludoTv);

        saludo.setText("Hola "+MainActivity.nombre.getText().toString()+ ", ¿Aceptas las condiciones?");

        Aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent Aceptar = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(Aceptar);
                MainActivity.decision.setText("Condiciones Aceptadas");

            }
        });

        Rechazar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent Rechazar = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(Rechazar);
                MainActivity.decision.setText("Condiciones Rechazadas");

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después que iniciaste `Main2Activity` ya no podés referenciar variables declaradas en `MainActivity`.

Para algo sencillo como esto, desde `MainActivity` podés llamar `startActivityForResult()` en luar de `startActivity()`, y luego desde `Main2Activity` volver a `MainActivity` retornando la opción elegida.

Para hacerte del resutlado tenes que implementar el callback `onActivityResult()` en `MainActivity()`.

En el código más abajo hice algunos cambios:
1. Hice los atributos de instancia quitando el modificador `static`
2. Los nombres de los atributos por convención los escribí en minúscula
3. `Activity1ForResult` viene a ser `MainActivity`.
4. `Activity2ForResult` viene a ser `Main2Activity`.
5. Quite las referencias desde `Main2Activity` hacia variables de `Main1Activity`.
6. Para mostrar en nombre en `Main2Activity`, inclué el nombre en el `Intent` que se envía desde `MainActivity`.

**Activity1ForResult (MainActivity)**

```
public class Activity1ForResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int IDENTIFICADOR_PEDIDO_1 = 1;

    Button siguiente;
    EditText nombre;
    TextView decision;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1_for_result);

        siguiente =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente);
        nombre =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
        decision =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDecision);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent siguiente = new Intent(Activity1ForResult.this, Activity2ForResult.class);
                siguiente.putExtra("nombre",nombre.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(siguiente, IDENTIFICADOR_PEDIDO_1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Procesar solo el resultado que corresponde al pedido que hicimos
        if (requestCode == IDENTIFICADOR_PEDIDO_1) {
            // Verificar que la llamada ocurrió sin error.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String respuesta = data.getStringExtra("respuesta");

                // Acá si podes referenciar la variable decisión y usar respuesta.
                // para setear el valor

                Activity1ForResult.this.decision.setText(respuesta);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity2ForResult (Main2Activity)**

```
public class Activity2ForResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button aceptar, rechazar;
    TextView saludo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2_for_result);

        aceptar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);
        rechazar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRechazar);
        saludo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSaludo);

        Intent intentRecibido = getIntent();
        String nombre = "";
        if(intentRecibido != null){
            nombre = intentRecibido.getStringExtra("nombre");
        }

        saludo.setText("Hola "+ nombre + ", ¿Aceptas las condiciones?");

        aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("respuesta", "Condiciones Aceptadas");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });

        rechazar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("respuesta", "Condiciones Rechazadas");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas @juan he estado probando tu solución y sigue sin funcionarme. Utilizando el debugger me he dado cuenta de que no entra al **onActivityResult**, por lo tanto no settea el texto.(de antemano perdón si estoy diciendo alguna locura soy nuevo en esto)

Comment: Revisé el código completo, por un lado yo había pegado mal el método de onActivityResult, y por otro había más cambios para hacer, por ejemplo quitar los Intent desde Main2Activity a MainActivity.